# Como eu faria pra tipar o meu context.Provider?

Tags: react, typescript, react-hooks

[image]
como vocês podem ver , o typescript está indentificando um problema no meu context.Provider, eu acredito que seja porque ele precisa ser tipado,nesse caso como eu faria para adicionar a devida tipagem?

Comment: Precisa disponibilizar o código, mas, é o tipo não está certo ou inexistente apesar que mesmo gera duvida se é isso mesmo por falta do código

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo:

```
type MyContextProps = {
globalData: Array<globalDataModel>;
setGlobalData: (globalData: Array<globalDataModel>; ) => void;
};
type MyProviderProps = {
children: ReactNode;
};
const MyContext = createContext({} as MyContextProps);

const MyProvider = ({ children }: MyProviderProps) => {
const [globalData, setGlobalData] = useState<globalDataModel>();

return (
  <MyContext.Provider value={{ globalData, setGlobalData }}>
    {children}
  </MyContext.Provider>
);
};
```

A finalidade do contexto e compartilhamento de dados globais para uma árvore de componentes, ele faz isso por meio do Componente Provedor,que aceita value como propriedade, por onde são passados esses dados globais:

```
 return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ globalData, setGlobalData }}>
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
```

è os tipos devem ser declarados, no Contexto,

```
type MyContextProps = {
  globalData: Array<globalDataModel>;
  setGlobalData: (globalData: Array<globalDataModel>; ) => void;
};

const MyContext = createContext({} as MyContextProps);
```

mais informações, consulte a documentação da biblioteca
[React](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html),

informações sobre o contexto: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score -1):

Como demonstrado na documentação do [useContext](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext),

> O valor de contexto atual é determinado pela prop value do<MyContext.Provider>mais próximo acima do componente de chamada na árvore.

E, de acordo com a imagem, você não forneceu a prop **value** pro seu **Provider**.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Você precisa tipar o contexto no momento de sua criação:

```
interface ContextData {
  user: User;
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
}

const MyContext = createContext<ContextData>();
```